# Thrift : TypeError: getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None

Tags: python, thrift

Hi I am trying to write a simple thrift server in python (named PythonServer.py) with a single method that returns a string for learning purposes. The server code is below. I am having the following errors in the Thrift's python libraries when I run the server. Has anyone experienced this problem and suggest a workaround?

The execution output:

```
    Starting server
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/dae/workspace/BasicTestEnvironmentV1.0/src/PythonServer.py", line     38,     in <module>
    server.serve()
    File "usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/thrift/server/TServer.py", line 101, in serve
    File "usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 136, in      listen
    File "usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 31, in      _resolveAddr
    TypeError: getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None
```

PythonServer.java

```
     port = 9090

     import MyService as myserv
     #from ttypes import *

     # Thrift files
     from thrift.transport import TSocket
     from thrift.transport import TTransport
     from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
     from thrift.server import TServer

     # Server implementation
     class MyHandler:
         # return server message
         def sendMessage(self, text):
             print text
             return 'In the garage!!!'


     # set handler to our implementation
     handler = MyHandler()

     processor = myserv.Processor(handler)
     transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port)
     tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
     pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

     # set server
     server = TServer.TThreadedServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

     print 'Starting server'
     server.serve() ##### LINE 38 GOES HERE ##########
```

Answer (score 19):

Your problem is the line:

```
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port)
```

When calling `TSocket.TServerSocket` which a single argument, the value is treated as a host identifier, hence the error with `getaddrinfo()`.

To fix that, change the line to:

```
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=port)
```

Comment: @farda Please reward correct answers by clicking the check-box.

Comment: @Shawn I started the server and get hangs on 
`Starting python server...`....
What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem while running PythonServer.py ...
I changed this line

```
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(9090)
```

to

```
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket('9090')
```

and my server started running.

Comment: // , Although this doesn't match the question's specific problem, I think this would help people searching for the error the OP got. Thanks for contributing, @Madhav Ramesh.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My fix is

```
TSocket.TServerSocket('your server ip',port)
```